# Jasmine: How test exception messages within a component?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

For my unit tests, I am ensuring that my components are calling the proper methods, then behaving appropriately if they do. The only trouble I have been having with these tests are when it comes to errors. I am trying to cause my service to fail, so that an exception message is displayed within an alert window. I am looking for insight on how to make my service fail, without causing the actual test to fail. Lets say I have a function that is similar to this:

```
 exceptionMessage: string = 'error, please contact administrator'  
getInfo() {
        this.myService.getData('url')

               .catch((error: Response | any) => {
                this.displayAlert(this.exceptionMessage);
                console.error(error.message || error);
                return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
              });
    };
```

Test:

```
    fit('should call displayAlert', () => {

   let window = spyOn(userComponent, 'displayAlert');

   spyOn(myService, 'getData').and.returnValue(Observable.of('url')//need to fail here

  userComponent.ngOnInit();
  userComponent.getInfo();
  expect(window).toHaveBeenCalled();

   });
```

When running the test, my code expects the spy, window to have been called. But since my service does not fail, I am unable to reach the displayAlert function in the code. Now I was able to successfully test that my services properly handle errors but they catch an observable and do not display an alert window like my component method does. I have tried to implement the test like my services but with no luck. My goal is to have a unit test, that causes my service to fail. From there I need to test that when my component encounters an error, an error message is displayed. I need the service to fail so that I can reach the code `this.displayAlert`Thank you! If anybody can guide me to proper documentation or provide insight, that would be great. I was unable to find much on this.

Edit: Updated Test:

```
 fit('should have getUsers() call showAlertWindow', () => {
   let window = spyOn(userComponent, 'showAlertWindow');
   spyOn(userComponent, 'loadUser').and.throwError('Error');

  expect(() => {
    userComponent.loadUser()}).toThrowError('Error');

    userComponent.loadUser();
    expect(window).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do, instead of calling `.and.returnValue`, is to throw an exception.

Something like this

```
spyOn(myService, 'getData').and.throwError(“My Error”)
```

This will make the `spy` throw an exception whenever it is called allowing to fall inside the catch statement where you can then test if the code inside is being called.

You can check `Jasmine` documentation [here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction)

Comment: Thank you. Now when doing `.and.throwError` is that actually causing the method that there is an error? Or is it just simulating an error catch. Reason being is I am trying to make the method fail so that showAlertWindow can be reached. Thanks.

Comment: It should simulate your api is returning an error. The whole point of using a spy is for you to have control on what is being returned on a specific call. Then you can set some expectations based on the behaviour you defined. So to answer your question, it should fall inside the catch

Comment: Ah gotcha. Now after throwing the error message, I then expect an error to be thrown. From there I call my getInfo component and then check if the alert window is called. Now Jasmine sees that the method fails and just returns `Error: error message`.  Calling my getInfo function `userComponent.getInfo` causes this error. Shouldn't the expect error expectation deal with this? Code is posted above.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you saying the expectation is not being triggered?

Comment: I belive that the function is not catching the error properly because running the test causes me to receive that error. When I run the line userComponent.getinfo, it causes the test to fail. I am trying to have the component catch the error so that I can reach the alertwindow function.

Comment: But in the edited test you seem to be using the spy on loadUser and not on getData. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I am honestly a little confused on if I should have the service fail or the component. My service catches an error that is created in the service class with a private method. Now when the service fails, that is handled in the service class, when the component fails, that should be handled within the component class, correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am just adding to @HugoNoro answer

After spying the methods like

```
let window = spyOn(userComponent, 'displayAlert');
spyOn(myService, 'getData').and.throwError(error.message)
....
```

You may also add a test to expect the error thrown from `getInfo()` along with `displayAlert` test

```
.......
expect(()=> { userComponent.getInfo(); }).toThrow(error.message); // error should be thrown from the component's catch block

expect(window).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Thank you. When I expect an error to be thrown, my test fails saying the error: 'my error message'. Do I need to pass an actual error from my component? Cause I just created a mock error message variable and passed that.

Comment: Mock your service to return the same message as of component message. Or else simply expect the message in your test to be component message that is thrown.

Comment: I solved that issue by modifying your line. `except(() =>....`But I am unsure how how to access the error, since in the component it is just a parameter. My test does not actually mock the method failing because of this, so the showAlert line is never reached.

Comment: `spyOn(myService, 'getData').and.throwError(error.message)` statement should throw the mock error and component `catch` block should be called. Isn't that working?

Comment: That is what I originally tried but jasmine states that it cannot find 'error'. My service's error handling  is a private service within my service class, so the error handling for the component is done within the component method.

Comment: You may return a mock error string literal like `Error while searching records` instead of a `error.message`. And then, your test should expect the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your myService was injected into the component you are testing, the spy would look like this.

```
spyOn(component['myService'], 'getData').and.returnValue(throwError({message: 'Foo'}));
```